# INDEX & MATCH in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have this table in excel

[image]

I want to create a new column where if have a total score let's say of 92 I do an index/match on the table and get it.
I tried this

```
=INDEX('Risk Assessment Matrix '!I24:I28,1,1,MATCH(111,'Risk Assessment Matrix '!J24:J28,0))
```

but not working.

Any help please?

Thanks,
Ilias

Comment: Show an example as even your formula seems odd: =INDEX('Risk Assessment Matrix '!I24:I28,MATCH(111,'Risk Assessment Matrix '!J24:J28,0)). may be better. Is 111 in the range J24:J28?

Comment: added in the main question ("here"). 111 was just a test

Comment: It would be helpful, ie save those who might want to help you, if you posted data and not an image.

Comment: Put column names at least on the photo. {I,H,L etc..}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a value given is not above 140, you don't even need a 3rd column. Try:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH(D1,B1:B5,-1))
```

If `D1` happens to be above 140 an error is returned. You can catch that by nesting the above in `=IFERROR(<TheAbove>,"No Match")` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Reorder the list so the third column is ascending not descending.  and change the `>=0` to just `0`

Then use:

```
=INDEX('Risk Assessment Matrix '!I24:I28,MATCH(111,'Risk Assessment Matrix '!K24:K28))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `INDEX/MATCH` looks a bit odd. You wouldn't normally have the "1,1," in there.

Try this:

```
=INDEX('Risk Assessment Matrix '!I24:I28, MATCH(111,'Risk Assessment Matrix '!J24:J28,0))
```

This should return "High" (assuming your first column in the table is "I".

Answer (score 0):

Two methods shown:

[image]

Pay attention to the order.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I understood the way to go about. Sorry for the hassle with the table

Answer (score 0):

An alternate option is the use the new XLOOKUP function.

Although it would require changing the minimum value range from 0 to -9999.  An out of range value for non-numeric values of 9999 would also need to be added.

It has the advantage of being easier to read compared to INDEX and MATCH.

```
=XLOOKUP($D2,$B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,"Not Found",-1)
```

The formula looks up the value against a single list of minimum values.

The match_mode (last parameter) is set to **-1**.  This means perform an exact match and if nothing is found return the next smaller item.

[image]